# System Permission Issue in android sdk

Tags: android, permissions, sdk, system

After updating Android SDK to 2.2.0, the system  permissions doesn't work.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hakobm.location">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

It's says that Manifest doesn't end with a final newline

Who knows why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

End the manifest at the end(after application).
{

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hakobm.location">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

}

Comment: it exist , sorry forgot to copy